# What does Jersey2 follows? Servlet-2 or Servlet-3 specifications

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0, servlet-2.5

I was curious to know if Jersey2 follows Servlet-2.5 specs or Servlet-3. I was using log4j2 into my jersey webapp project and the way it is needed to configure depends on the Servlet types.

For reference https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

Comment: [Jersey supports both 2.x and 3.x](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Can you please give me some resource to check how to use Jersey for Servlet-3

Comment: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3